# Simple way to get complex array value or null

Tags: javascript, arrays, error-handling, split

This here throws an error if it can't match at any point in the call down the array. I'd like it to set the value to null instead. How can I achieve something like this?

```
let value = def[0].split('@')[0] || null
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's on approach:

```
export function t (tryFunc, catchFunc) {
  try {
    return tryFunc()
  } catch (e) {
    return catchFunc
  }
}

let name = t(() => def[0].split('@')[0], null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `def[0].split('@')[1] ? def[0].split('@')[0] : null;` checking if exits def[0], although I prefer to include the code inside a function for readability.

```
function someContextName(def) {
    if(def[0])
        return def[0].split('@')[1] ? def[0].split('@')[0] : null;
    return null;
}
```